# PHP Keeps Previous Javascript Cookie Value

Tags: javascript, cookies

This little snipped of code is supposed to call a javascript function that creates cookie, then PHP reads and deletes it.  My problem is that in successive runs, the PHP gets the cookie value of the previous run.  On the first run of a session, if I set user_data to 123,  it fails and PHP says the cookie is not set. (I can see in the console the cookie is set.)  I refresh page and put 456 in javascript but PHP returns 123, if I run again and enter 789, PHP returns 456.  And PHP NEVER deletes the cookie.  Why?

Here's the code, complete with debug lines.

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie() {
    var data = prompt("Enter data");
    document.cookie = "user_data="+data;
}
</script>
</head>
<?php
var_dump($_COOKIE);
if (true) {
    echo "Running script<br>";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">setCookie();</script>';
}
sleep(5);
var_dump($_COOKIE);

if(isset($_COOKIE["user_data"])) { 
    $data=$_COOKIE['user_data'];
    setcookie('user_data', '', 1, '/');
    unset($_COOKIE['user_data']);
} else {
    $data="Cookie not set!";
}
echo "The user_data is: $data<br>";
?>
```

There seems to be an odd issue with that sleep(5) -- it seems like the first thing the program does.  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it two separate files. Front and back end. Read, create and delete cookie with JS, post data to the PHP if you need it.

Comment: It was two separate files with JavaScript in an include, but it did produced the same results decribed above.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, cookies are front end. Yes PHP can read and modify cookies but in this case it shouldn't. There is a lag involved in calling php backend from frontend and possible bugs and mistakes. Only time it is ok to call cookies from PHP is if it isn't critical and time sensitive and then should be used sparingly. There is no security benefit to doing PHP cookie read vs JS cookie read.

Comment: To clarify, delete everything where PHP deals with cookies and implement js counter part that calls php through post. Delete isset($_COOKIE["user_data"]) and set from PHP. Use JS to set and check if there is a cookie.

Comment: Pro tip, provide public key to encrypt data to js from php. Store private key in backend. Then verify the encryption and decrypt later in backend. That way, nobody could maliciously eddit fronend data and post it to php.